# Convert WebSQL epoch format to Javascript date

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I have a Timestamp field in a WebSQL database that is stored like:

/Date(1340420400000)/

When I pull that value out of the db, a literal string is returned to me, and I have to extract the epoch value with a RegEx, parse it as an int, and pass it into a Javascript Date. Is there an easier way to do this, it seems rather clumsy.

I know I could use the SQLLite strftime function, but I'd prefer to use "SELECT *" as I have many large tables and I'd like to avoid identifying each and every field in all my queries.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are so lazy, then you could write

```
SELECT t.*, strftime('%whatever',t.Timestamp) AS formatted_timestamp
FROM t
...
```

Or rename the `Timestamp` column to `_Timestamp`:

```
SELECT t.*, strftime('%whatever',t._Timestamp) AS _Timestamp
FROM t
...
```

Alternatively / additionally you could make a view for every table for selecting.